# What is the purpose of the #SET TERMINATOR statement

Tags: sql, db2

Specifically for SQL stored procedures. Am I supposed to include it at the beginning of every stored procedure such as

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE Name
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Table
END
@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a statement, it's a directive to change the statement terminator.
You must use another statement terminator different from the default one (`;`), if a statement you want to run contains a [compound statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-compound-statements) (with `BEGIN ... END`) containing other "simple" statements delimited by `;`. The statement delimiter inside a compound statement can't be changed, so you have to help the DB2 Command Line Processor to understand, where your whole "complex" statement ends.

BTW, your statement contains a number of mistakes. Each statement (including the last one) inside the `BEGIN ... END` block must be separated by `;`, and you can't "SELECT to nowhere" in a routine.

Comment: Thanks Mark! That explanation definitely clears a lot of things up and helps me understand what I need to work on.

Comment: @LaidBackLuck If you find an answer useful you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for pointing that out! Pretty new here so still trying to figure things out.